# undo on canvas is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to add undo functionality in canvas. But it is not working correctly.

Issue -

Let say i have drawn 3 line separately on canvas, but when i have start doing undo on it ,

2nd click - it shows 2 lines

3rd click - it show 1 line

When i start to draw again on canvas, all lines redrawn i.e, all three lines redrawn

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc67eaop/) and draw on it

My code below

**HTML**

`<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
 <input type='button' onClick='undoDrawOnCanvas();' id='btnUndo' value='Undo drawing'>`

**CSS**

`canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }`

**JS**

```
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;
var restorePoints = [];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
};
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (isDrawing) {
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};
el.onmouseup = function() {
    isDrawing = false;
    saveRestorePoint();
};


function saveRestorePoint() {
    var oCanvas = document.getElementById("c");
    var imgSrc = oCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    restorePoints.push(imgSrc);
}


function undoDrawOnCanvas() {
    if (restorePoints.length > 0) {
       var oImg = new Image();
       oImg.onload = function() {
           ctx.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);            
           ctx.drawImage(oImg, 0, 0);
       }
       oImg.src = restorePoints.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheFourthBird is right, your problem is that you don't call `ctx.beginPath` in the mousedown event. Also, for your undo functionnality, avoid the use of `toDataURL`, this is a really unefficient way to do it. Instead, you should save all your drawing operations (here it would be easy saving all coords in arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `beginPath()` to the `onmousedown` event.

Maybe the updated code in this fiddle is what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/dc67eaop/4/

Comment: You don't want to use `ctx.closePath()`